# Where and how to define a generic function, if multiple packages are used

Tags: r, generics

I know there are related posts, but with insufficient answers. So please answer seriously to this question.

There are two packages ("keithley" and "xantrex") which control two different hardware devices. Therefore, both are independent from each other. Each of them must be initialised separately. So I wrote two methods

```
init.keithley(inst,...) # in keythley package
```

and

```
init.xantrex(inst,...) # in xantrex package
```

for the generic S3 function `init(inst,...)`. I tried to declare the generic function in the `keithley` package and in the `xantrex` package, but then it is masked, once the latter is loaded and the methods where not found any more.

What I tried is the `.onAttach()`-hook

```
.onAttach <- function(libname, pkgname)
{
  if(!exists("init"))
    eval(expression(init <- function(inst,...) UseMethod("init")),envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

But with this it is NOT possible to evaluate the `init()` function within the package namespace. This can be proofed with the option `envir = environment()`, which will not work. I also tried `setGenericS3()` and `setGeneric()` with always the same result. 
The "dirty" solution could be to define a third package and import it, but there must be a clean way to do this.

Where and how should I define the generic function?

Comment: Does the following work? `keithley::init(...)` and `xantrex::init(...)`

Comment: This should work, but is not intended. One should use these packages with lines like `init(keith)` and `init(xan)` and so on, with out calling the namespace explicitly.

Comment: does `environment(init) <- asNamespace('xantrex')` work? to be used in your onAttach

Comment: I would suggest you don't use a generic function and methods, but simply `init.keithly()` and `init.xantrex()`.  There seems to be little value in shared infrastructure if the packages are entirely independent. And if they are not independent, then your "dirty" solution may well be the only solution. (PS - it doesn't sound dirty to me at all.)

Comment: @Andrie the packages are independent in the sense, that they do not share code, but technological they might be conjunct. My intension is to write user friendly code, where `init(keith)` and `init(xan)` will initialize the corresponding devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

As I understand, an attached package has three environments (e.g. `"package:Xantrex"`, `"namespace:Xantrex"` and `"imports:Xantrex"`) the different meaning of these is explained in detail here: [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html).

Now, we have to test whether the generic function `init()` is already there and if not we have to initialize it in the right environment. The following code will do that for us.

```
.onAttach <- function(libname, pkgname)
{
  if(!exists("init",mode = "function"))
    eval(expression(init <- function(inst,...) UseMethod("init")),envir = as.environment("package:Xantrex"))
}
```

The `.onAttach`-hook, is necessary to guarantee that the different namespaces are initialized. In contrast to that the `.onLoad`-hook, would be too early. Mention that the expression is evaluated in the `package:Xantrex` environment, so the generic becomes visible in the search path.

Next to that take care, that your NAMESPACE file will `export(init.xantrex)` and **NOT** `S3method(init,xantrex)`. The latter will result an error, because the generic for the method `init.xantrex()`is not present while building the package.

Best!
Martin